# jQuery animation not working on chrome

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome

I am making a panel with three sections to show some info and using jQuery for that.

Everything works perfectly in FF, but Chrome somehow does not animate removeClass, however it animates addClass that comes later!

I made a fiddle, try it on FF and then on Chrome to see the difference of animation on the hover action: http://jsfiddle.net/cqg6r/2/

I am guessing the problem is in this piece:

```
jQuery(this).removeClass("shown", 1000);
```

However, I am digging and googling all day and cannot see where exactly it is.

(Please excuse if my code is messy, I am a newbie. Also, I am working with jQuery instead of $ because the website in question runs on WordPress.)

Comment: All the animation work on my Chrome browser.  Use F12 to open the Chrome debugger and check the console to see if you have any errors.

Comment: I have also tried in both browser and its working fine for me.

Comment: It works, but differently then it should. The panels should open and close slowly, now they open quick and just close slowly. You have to check it on FF to see the difference...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use animate for this

here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mitali/cqg6r/3/)   link

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(".filter1, .filter2, .filter3").hover(function(){
     jQuery(this).stop().dequeue().animate({right:'0'},1000);
  }, function(){
     jQuery(this).stop().dequeue().animate({right:'-380px'},1000);
  });
});
```

Comment: Niiice. I see what you did here, but would have never thought about it myself. I still need a lot to learn. Thank you very much!

Comment: :) and u can use $ sign instead of jQuery .. (function($){// your code})(jQuery);  put your all code in this n use $ if you want to..